# Using smartcard credentials, obtained by a webpage

Tags: web-services, authentication, active-directory, smartcard

I have two servers on a Windows domain that include an active directory that is correctly configured to allow users to login using smartcard credentials. Currently, I can login to server1 and run remote PowerShell commands on server2 using smartcard credentials through WinRM, without any problem.

I would like to build some sort of web service (preferably on node.js) on server1, so that it presents a user with a webpage that prompts for smartcard credentials. Using these credentials, server1 would be able to run remote PowerShell commands on server2.

Is this possible? I saw some references to pcsclite on other posts. Is this all I need? If so, could someone provide a code snip-it of something that could accomplish this?

Maybe a simpler question that could help me get started, would be how could I even use these credentials to connect to a file share on server2 and download a file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look int using [WAP in IIS](https://www.ssltrust.com.au/blog/setup-web-application-proxy-server/)  to set up a gateway and use [Active Directory Client certificate mapping](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770480(v=ws.10).aspx)